# What are the benefits of using TcpClient over a Socket directly?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I understand that a TcpClient is a wrapper around the socket class, and I can access the underlying socket if using the TcpClient, but what exactly does the wrapper do?

When using the TCPClient do i need to keep calling Receive() like I do with a socket or does the wrapper ensure all my data appears?

Lastly, can I use the TcpClient on both the server and the client to wrap the socket (after using TcpListener to accept the original connection on the server)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> what exactly does the wrapper do?

Let me explain this with an example. You have a method in C# `File.ReadAllLines`. It reads all lines in the file for you. Now you can also achieve same results via `FileStream` class or any other class which reads file .. BUT.. wrapper i.e. `File.ReadAllLines`, allows you to achieve the same with less lines of code. Wrappers always increase productivity by abstracting out the low level details

> When using the TCPClient do i need to keep calling Receive() like I do
>   with a socket or does the wrapper ensure all my data appears?

`TCPClient` don't have a `Receive` method like `Socket` but the idea is same. You will have to use methods like `GetStream` to read the data it won't automagically appear for you

> Can I use the TcpClient on both the server and the client to wrap the
>   socket

Yes, you can safely use it on both client and server side

Comment: Ah I see. So am I right in saying that equivalent of performing _BeginReceive(), followed by EndReceive(), store bytes and recall BeginReceive() again until message received_  on a socket, can be performed by using _myTcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead()_  on a TcpClient? Will BeginRead() not call the EndRead() callback until the specified number of bytes received has indeed been received? (removing the need to constantly call BeginRead()/BeginReceive() until all expected bytes have been received)

Comment: I would prefer to use `Read` and `Write` methods of `NetworkStream` class instead of `BeginRead` and `EndRead` because you won't have to explicitly call `BeginRead` and `EndRead` the wrapper would do it for you. See some samples on internet like this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx