# Communication server-client (TcpClient or Socket?)

Tags: c#

I will try to create a server and a client (just to communicate with each other) and I see on the internet I have the option of tcpClient and the option of Socket.

So, I would like to know which of these two is the better way, to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TcpClient is just a wrapper for Socket, and is more high-level. More info in link below:
[What are the benefits of using TcpClient over a Socket directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552916/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-tcpclient-over-a-socket-directly)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Marios if my answer is enough for you please accept it, thanks.